# How to print an equal sign when there are series?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex for bibliographic information and sometimes have books which are part of a series. If this is the case, then the title of the series must go into the bibliography with a leading equal sign (`=`).

[image: example screenshot of bibliography with =]

A MWE is below. I couldn't find a matching style so far. I never went down the rabbit hole to create an own style. My hope is/was that someone knows of a style which accomplishes this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{key,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    series = {Best Series},
  }
\end{filecontents}                                                                                                             
\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I realise this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? What style do you use? How does an example `.bib` file look like. In general we can say that something like this should be possible, but the solution very much depends on the style you use and on the general set-up of your bibliography. Please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) so we can see the style you use, have something to get started and can test our solutions with your set-up.

Comment: How would citations look like in your style? Author-Title? Author-Year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not married to a particular style already, I suggest you use one of the `biblatex-dw` family.

With the option `series=afteryear` and

```
\renewcommand*{\seriespunct}{=\addspace}
```

you get close to what you want.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw, series=afteryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\seriespunct}{=\addspace}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  location = {Den Haag},
  series = {Best Series},
  number = {7},
}
\end{filecontents}                                                                                                             
\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> Author, A.: Title, Den Haag 2001 (= Best Series 7).